# Редирект с основного домена на домен с портом

Tags: dns, openserver, port

Всем привет. Кто ни будь знает, возможно ли сделать редирект на OpenServer, чтобы с основного домена редиректило на домен + порт. Открыт не стандартный порт, потому что так надо!

Comment: ну просто добавьте номер порта. после двоеточия. вы что, не в курсе как это написать? объясняю: двоеточие — это `:`, а номер порта — это число, состоящее из десятичных цифр.

Comment: но вообще, судя по вот этой приписке — «потому что так надо!» (с восклицательным знаком в конце) вы явно делаете совсем не то, что вам на самом деле надо.

Comment: Орнул конечно. Я имею ввиду чтобы с основного домена например test.ru редиректило на test.ru с портом :1234. Поняли суть вопроса? Так надо,  потому что у компании на сервере открыт только один внешний порт. Поэтому я и спрашиваю где настроить редирект.